How come the 'find' command works correctly in the terminal but not when run from a bash file?
I'm a beginner in Bash scripting. I'm using Kali Linux. I wrote a bash file. It's supposed to ask for user input to fill in every single parameter of the command and then at the end, it will echo out the full command, that it intends to execute, in simple text form, and then execute that exact command with all the given information (The command that it's supposed to execute in the end is "find"). Everything works fine except for the last part where it's supposed to execute the "find" command.  This is an example:
find '/home/kali/Desktop' -type f -user 'kali' -iname 'this text file.txt'

I copied this line and executed it from the terminal directly with all the same arguments and it worked, but when I indirectly executed it through the Bash file, it didn't work. And it kept saying "find: ‘'kali'’ is not the name of a known user".
find '/home/kali/Desktop' -type f -user kali -iname 'this text file.txt'

When I removed the quotes around the word "kali", it gave me this as output: "find: paths must precede expression: `text'"
I tried using "sh" and "bash" followed by the file's name as parameter in the terminal like this:
sh <filename>
bash <filename>

and it still didn't work. I even tried changing the shebang from #!/usr/bin/env bash to #!/bin/bash, but it still didn't work.
Here's the full code of the bash script that I wrote:
#!/bin/bash
true_path=""
find_type=""
all_types=("f" "d" "l" "c" "b" "p")
find_name=""
find_user=""
find_group=""
declare -A byte_math
keys=("c" "w" "b" "k" "M" "G")
values=(1 2 512 1024 1048576 1073741824)
for ((i = 0; i < ${#keys[@]}; i++)); do
    byte_math["${keys[i]}"]="${values[i]}"
done
all_units=("c" "w" "b" "k" "M" "G")
lower_limit_size_in_bytes=""
upper_limit_size_in_bytes=""
find_size_ll=""
find_size_ul=""

function step1 () { # Asking for the path
    read -p "
Where do you want to search? (enter path):

/home/kali/" path
    if ! [[ -d "/home/kali/${path}" ]]; then
        echo "
Invalid directory path. Try Again."
        path=""
        step1
        return 0
    fi
    true_path+="'/home/kali/${path}' "
    step2
}

function step2 () {
    read -p "
Do you want to add another path? (Y/N): " repeat
    if [[ "${repeat,,}" == "y" ]]; then
        step1
    elif ! [[ "${repeat,,}" == "y" || "${repeat,,}" == "n" ]]; then
        echo "  
Invalid Input. Try Again."
        repeat=""
        step2
        return 0
    fi
    return 0
}

step1

echo "
All paths given: ${true_path} "

function step3 () { # Asking for "-type" parameter
    read -p "
Type of files or folders you want to search for:
    f: Regular files
    d: Directories
    l: Symbolic link
    c: Character devices
    b: Block devices
    p: Named pipes (FIFO)
    skip: skip
    
    Which type?: " type_filter # If the user chooses "skip", it will skip this option
    
    if [[ " ${all_types[*]} " == *" ${type_filter,,} "* ]]; then
        find_type="-type ${type_filter,,} "
    elif ! [[ "${type_filter,,}" == "skip" ]]; then
        echo "
Invalid type. Try Again."
        type_filter=""
        step3
        return 0
    fi
    return 0
}

step3

echo "
${find_type}"

function step4 () { # Asking for the name of the file/directory that the user is looking for
    read -p "
Do you want to specify the name of the files/folders? [Y/N]: " name_Y_N
    if [[ "${name_Y_N,,}" == "y" ]]; then
        read -p "
File/Folder name: " file_foldername
        find_name="-iname '${file_foldername}' "
    elif [[ "${name_Y_N,,}" != "n" && "${name_Y_N,,}" != "y" ]]; then
        echo "
Invalid input. Try Again."
        name_Y_N=""
        step4
        return 0
    fi
    return 0
}


function step5 () { # Asking if the user wants to specify the user of the file they're looking for
    read -p "
Do you want to look for files/folders owned by a specific user? [Y/N]: " user_Y_N
    if [[ "${user_Y_N,,}" == "y" ]]; then
        read -p "
Username: " username
        find_user="-user ${username} "
    elif [[ "${user_Y_N,,}" != "n" && "${user_Y_N,,}" != "y" ]]; then
        echo "
Invalid input. Try Again."
        user_Y_N=""
        step5
        return 0
    fi
    return 0
} 

step5

echo "
${find_user}"

function step6 () { # Same as the one above but with group
    read -p "
Do you want to look for files/folders owned by a specific group? [Y/N]: " group_Y_N
    if [[ "${group_Y_N,,}" == "y" ]]; then
        read -p "
Group name: " groupname
        find_group="-group '${groupname}' "
    elif [[ "${group_Y_N,,}" != "n" && "${group_Y_N,,}" != "y" ]]; then
        echo "
Invalid input. Try Again."
        group_Y_N=""
        step6
        return 0
    fi
    return 0
} 

step6

echo "
${find_group}"

function step7 () { # From here (step7 to step 11) is just asking for size specification
    read -p "
Do you want to specify the size of the files/folders that you're looking for? [Y/N]: " size_Y_N
    if [[ "${size_Y_N,,}" == "y" ]]; then
        step8
    elif [[ "${size_Y_N,,}" != "n" && "${size_Y_N,,}" != "y" ]]; then
        echo "
Invalid Input. Try Again."
        size_Y_N=""
        step7
        return 0
    fi
    return 0
}

function step8 () {
    read -p "
Do you want to specify a lower limit for the size of the files that you're looking for? [Y/N]: " lower_limit_Y_N
    if [[ "${lower_limit_Y_N,,}" == "y" ]]; then
        step9
    elif [[ "${lower_limit_Y_N,,}" != "y" && "${lower_limit_Y_N,,}" != "n" ]]; then
        echo "
Invalid Input. Try Again."
        lower_limit_Y_N=""
        step8
        return 0
    fi
    step10
    return 0
}

function step10 () {
    read -p "
Do you want to specify a upper limit for the size of the files that you're looking for? [Y/N]: " upper_limit_Y_N
    if [[ "${upper_limit_Y_N,,}" == "y" ]]; then
        step11
    elif [[ "${upper_limit_Y_N,,}" != "y" && "${upper_limit_Y_N,,}" != "n" ]]; then
        echo "
Invalid Input. Try Again."
        upper_limit_Y_N=""
        step10
        return 0
    fi
    return 0
}

function step9 () {
    read -p "
Lower Limit. Choose your byte unit (Case Sensitive):
    c: Bytes
    w: Words (1 word = 2 bytes)
    b: 512-byte blocks
    k: Kilobytes (1024 bytes)
    M: Megabytes (1024 kilobytes)
    G: Gigabytes (1024 megabytes)
    
    Unit: " lower_limit_unit
    # $lower_limit_unit=${lower_limit_unit,,}
    if ! [[ " ${all_units[*]} " == *" ${lower_limit_unit} "* ]]; then
        echo "
Invalid unit. Try Again."
        lower_limit_unit=""
        step9
        return 0
    fi
    read -p "
Enter size in number: " lower_limit_size
    find_size_ll="-size +${lower_limit_size}${lower_limit_unit} "
    return 0
}

function step11 () {
    read -p "
Upper Limit. Choose your byte unit (Case Sensitive):
    c: Bytes
    w: Words (1 word = 2 bytes)
    b: 512-byte blocks
    k: Kilobytes (1024 bytes)
    M: Megabytes (1024 kilobytes)
    G: Gigabytes (1024 megabytes)
    
    Unit: " upper_limit_unit
    # $upper_limit_unit=${upper_limit_unit,,}
    if ! [[ " ${all_units[*]} " == *" ${upper_limit_unit} "* ]]; then
        echo "
Invalid unit. Try Again."
        upper_limit_unit=""
        step11
        return 0
    fi
    read -p "
Enter size in number: " upper_limit_size
    if [[ -n $find_size_ll ]]; then
        upper_limit_size_in_bytes=$(($upper_limit_size * ${byte_math[$upper_limit_unit]}))
        lower_limit_size_in_bytes=$(($lower_limit_size * ${byte_math[$lower_limit_unit]}))
        if [[ $upper_limit_size_in_bytes -lt $lower_limit_size_in_bytes ]]; then
            echo "
    Error. Upper limit size (${upper_limit_size_in_bytes} bytes) can't be smaller than lower limit size (${lower_limit_size_in_bytes} bytes). Try Again."
            step9
            step10
            return 0
        fi
    fi
    find_size_ul="-size -${upper_limit_size}${upper_limit_unit} "
    return 0
}

step7

echo "
${find_size_ll}${find_size_ul}"

step4

echo "
${find_name}"

echo "
find ${true_path}${find_type}${find_user}${find_group}${find_size_ll}${find_size_ul}${find_name}
" # Here it will echo out the command in plain text before executing it on the line below

find ${true_path}${find_type}${find_user}${find_group}${find_size_ll}${find_size_ul}${find_name} # Here's where the command gets executed


See BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail! -- the very short form is that you can't use literal quotes (quotes in your data) as if they were quotes in your syntax, and when you need to build a command dynamically, you should do that using shell arrays, not strings.

(As a completely unrelated matter that has nothing to do with your problem -- function funcname() { merges the 1980s ksh syntax function funcname { and the modern (1990s) POSIX sh syntax funcname() { into an amalgam that's needlessly incompatible with both legacy ksh and POSIX sh; bash only supports function for ksh backwards compatibility, and even then it's not quite compatible with the original ksh behavior where its use changed behavior of typeset; there's no reason to use it in modern code).

Also see "Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?" In general, if you need to build a command (or list of command arguments), use an array rather than a plain string (and avoid the temptation to use eval -- it is a massive bug magnet).

nod; see also BashFAQ #48 if otherwise feeling tempted to use eval.

BTW, note that all variables in shell are global unless you explicitly declare otherwise. If you want the various path variables you define in your functions to be local to those functions, you'll want the line local path to be present within that function.

(As a completely different, language-agnostic piece of advice -- try to get out of the habit of treating recursion as if it were a GOTO; that's a habit that tends to bite people, either by way of running out of stack, or unintended side effects of the unwinding process; typically the cases where this is done are situations where an explicit state machine or a top-level function that calls children in turn will make more sense).

Thx @GordonDavisson, I used "bash -c" and it worked, thank u so much bro

@FrustratedProgrammer bash -c has most of the same problems that eval has -- it essentially runs the shell parsing process twice, so it has the potential to parse (and even execute) things you thought were just static data (e.g. filenames). Seriously, use arrays for things like this.
